# how to configure alb to point to new masterinstance(EMR) after failover

Tags: apache-spark, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr, failover, aws-application-load-balancer

WE are launching an ALB to access various UIs of the EMR services. But when we enable the High availability of EMR launching 3 master nodes, how will the alb automatically points out to new masternode thats active. The ALB should not distribute the traffic to secondary instances. It need to point to the whatever instance which is acting as master at a given time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need **custom solution** for that. For example you can setup a lambda function that gets triggered based on alarm constructed using `MultiMasterInstanceGroupNodesRunningPercentage` metric. Once trigger, the lambda function with de-register old muster with a target group of your ALB, and register a new one.

Comment: considering the lambda function is triggered, how will the lambda function will know the lastest master instance? it can be either of two healthy instances right? Please correct me if i am wrong. So my lambda function should read the instanceid from the clusterdetails then pass it to ALB?

Comment: @shivanagesh I don't know all the details, thus you need fully custom solution developed from scratch. This requires test EMR setup and replication of your scenario to identify answers to all these questions.